# Can Admin rights be gained as a standard user in win 10 without a boot disk

Tags: windows-10

I am working on a school laptop without admin rights and would like to install eclipse IDE because Notepad++ isn't cutting it.

Comment: no, not without an exploit for an unpatched escalation of privileges vulnerability.

Comment: Does the Sticky Keys privilege escalation exploit still work?

Comment: @Gantendo, no I believe that was windows7, and IIRC you needed to have admin previously to replace the executables, or to have set it up using an alternate boot environment. Since op has excluded an alternate boot, its pretty tricky.

Comment: @FrankThomas Kinda sucks if they've patched that. I loved doing that in the bad old days. Oh well.

Comment: me too. made me feel like a L33T H4x0r.... ;-)

Comment: If your actual intention is to use Eclipse,  you can (potentially) use a portable version of Eclipse ([SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-neon-portable/)) ([GitHub](https://github.com/Berny23/eclipse-portable)) that runs from USB mass storage (e.g. a USB stick).

Comment: Thank you, I think the eclipse portable is going to work just fine. I'm new to this site and the response was both speedy and informative. Thanks again

Comment: @Gantendo sticky keys was Windows 7. For Windows 10 there is a similar hack that uses utilman and a button on the login screen.

Comment: @LPChip Sounds like that annoying Windows Defender has patched that hole unfortunately https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150847/bypassing-windows-10-password-with-utilman-exe-trick-fixed https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/windows-defender-can-detect-accessibility-tool-backdoors/

Comment: @Gantendo no, it has not been patched out, only that exploit was. In fact, it still works in Windows 11, but then you need to boot in safe mode with network options.

Comment: This laptop doesn't belong to you and the owners of this laptop have the right to control what you may run on it.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to download and use
[Eclipse Portable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-neon-portable/).

It will work without installation.

Comment: Thank you. i think the eclipse portable is going to work. New to this site and the feedback was speedy and usable. Thanks again.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).